# How can I implement a split view like the one in Number and Pages?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I implement a splitter like the ones in Pages and Number? (the ones with a handle on the side):

[image: Splitter on numbers]
[image: Splitter on pages]

What is used to implement them? A source list or an outline view?

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle `splitView:additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAtIndex:` in you `NSSplitViewDelegate` to return an additional rectangle in which mouse clicks will initiate divider dragging.

You can make custom outline/tableView header to draw a handle and specify it's rect in `splitView:additionalEffectiveRectOfDividerAtIndex:`.

Comment: This answer is correct. Just want to add there is an example project in the docs, Splitviews.xcodeproj that has an example on how to implement this.